# How do I use NgXs in nestjs framework?

Tags: nestjs, ngxs

I was requested to use Ngxs on nestjs. As far as I know, Ngxs is written exclusively for Angular, dispute that nestjs is very similar to Angular in terms of application structure. Hopefully someone can provide assistance in either

1. how to fit in ngxs in nestjs, or
2. any useful materials I can used to write some sort of adapter to do it, or
3. who/how to get someone to do it for me?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make sense to port ngxs to nest. Why would you like to do it?

Comment: I think it can make sense when building a (small) game for example. If persistency is not a concern, dealing with all the state issues using Redux might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense.

If you want to use redux in nextjs, please, use some redux approach for it.

For example:
https://github.com/Wildhoney/redux-nest